# In what way can I still use an old, still functioning laptop since I bought a new one?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, code, open-source

I recently purchased a new laptop and am not using the old one. I feel it is a waste for the old one to just be put away on my shelf collecting dust. It is an ASUS laptop with Intel Celeron 3060 with 4 GB RAM and 500 GB HDD.

I was wondering if there were any creative ways to utilize it other than using it occasionally for simple tasks and as an HDD.

Comment: Unfortunately, the question is way too broad.  An old laptop can be used for countless things.  However, since you cant actually think of a need, then more than likely, you dont *actually* need it.  Google what you can use an old laptop for.

Comment: I'd use it to multibox mobile game emulators using nox, but that's just me...

Comment: If you choose to sell it or donate it, I'd recommend removing the old HDD first. Files are never gone forever, and you can buy an external enclosure for on the order of $10 so you can make use of that drive. If you have any interest in working with computers, an old laptop that you don't mind breaking is also a good playground for learning to take apart laptops, identifying components, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You could consider donating it to a local school or Goodwill.  You could consider using it as a media player / server with something like KODI if it has HDMI, but that could be more trouble than it's worth if you already have an AppleTV, Chromecast or Roku.  There's really a nearly endless number of possibilities, but it depends on the value of your time and also the power efficiency of using an old laptop.  For example, you could use it to act as a network attached storage (NAS), but that's way overpowered and uses far more energy than a dedicated NAS or using a low-powered computer like a Raspberry Pi.  Again - donating it to a charitable cause or underserved community could be best.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are into the scene of coding or programming or perhaps are interested in that but suppose you were, I'd recommend putting Linux on it and since there are so many distributions I'd start out with Ubuntu since it is the most mainstream then if you want to branch out - by all means do so. :D

What I would personally do if you don't already use your new machine to do this is hook up your old laptop to your TV and watch YouTube with some sort of adblock (I.e. uBlock Origin) enabled and viola... entertainment without ads. (Ads on YouTube have become too abundant, if you ask me.)